# Camunda ENGINE-02006 No conditional sequence flow leaving the Flow Node

Tags: java, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have quite big camunda BPMN definition with lots of variables in context. Some of variables combinations leads to end events and some are not (which raise error from subject)
It is very complicated to make sure that every possible combination for variables will lead to some end event.

I wonder if I can implement logic when in case of no condition is met on some node, this branch will and with some NOOP value and not interrupt whole process.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can mark on exit of the gateway as "default" flow which will be taken when no condition matches.

Comment: This is not an option for me as I have lots of gateways. The solution I've found so far is post-processing of process and adding those default escape paths programmatically.